# Probability Question

Tags: probability

how would I be able to answer this question?

The first box contains 3 white and 7 black balls, and the second box contains 6 white and 3 black balls, A ball is chosen at random from the first box, and, without looking at its colour, put into the second box. Then a ball is chosen at random from the second box, and it is white. Is it more likely that the ball moved from the first box to the second was black?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Bayes theorem, but the context is confusing me

Comment: A very similar question was asked yesterday (?) by abcd8642. You will probably find the solutions a sufficient guide if you want to compute.

Comment: 2/3 for transferring a black then?